# meteor rendering eachitem inside a style block template

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I'm trying to allow personalized style setting to be persisted inside a meteor app.  For sake of argument, lets say I'm keeping the values in an array of objects, each object containing a "name' and "value" attribute.  When I try to render these objects inside a <style> block, Meteor instead renders a comment.
The following it my simplest Proof of Concept:

poc.html:

```
<head>                                                                  
 <title>poc</title>                                                    
</head>                                                                                                                                         
<body>                                                                  
  {{> hello}}                                                           
</body>                                                                                                                                        
<template name="hello">                                                 
<h1>Hello World!</h1>                                                   
 Styles don't render here:                                               
<style>                                                                 
    body {background-color: #999;}                                      
    {{#each styles}}                                                    
  .{{name}} { {{value}} }                                             
  {{/each}}                                                           
</style>                                                                

Styles render here:                                                   
<ul>                                                                  
    {{#each styles}}                                                  
    <li class="{{name}}">{{name}} : {{value}}</li>                    
    {{/each}}                                                         
</ul>                                                                 
And here:                                                             
<div>                                                                 
    {{#each styles}}                                                  
    .{{name}} { {{value}} } <br/>                                     
    {{/each}}                                                         
</div>
```

poc.js:

```
   if (Meteor.isClient) {                                                  
     Template.hello.styles= function() {                                   
                 var resultArray=[];                                       
                 resultArray.push( { name: 'style1', value:'color: #000'}) 
                 resultArray.push( { name: 'style2', value:'color: #fff'}) 
                 return resultArray;                                       
            }                                                             
    }
```

The output in the style block contains:

```
 <!--data:DuvxkGSiN6BK3M95T--><!--data:GvvkPYg2Adii4NNre-->
```

instead of the expected:

```
 style1: { color: #000}
 style2: { color: #fff}
```

Not sure if this is by design or a bug or an error in my understanding.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor does some special things with markup that might be interfering with rendering inside the style tag.

There are two solutions-

if you just need to add static styles, add the following helper and render it with three braces `{{{styleBlock styles}}}`  as a separate element:

```
Template.hello.styleBlock = function(styles){
  content = "<style>";
  _.each(styles, function(style){
    content += '.' + style.name + '{' + style.value + '}';
  });
  content += "</style>";
  return content;
};
```

Or if you need to dynamically add styles, you can set up an observe that finds the style sheet and calls '[insertRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet.insertRule)'

```
var styleSheet = _.find(document.styleSheets, 
        function(sheet){return sheet.ownerNode.getAttribute("id") == 'dynamic-styles';}
    );
    styleSheet.insertRule('.style1{color: #000}', 0);
```

Comment: it's been confirmed that meteor doesn't render inside style tags correctly (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1460). Since these are reactive, I'm not sure how well the second option will work as i would need to remove those at times too.

Comment: You'd need to track the rule index, the use deleteRule to remove them. You could also flush and re-add the rules on delete.  Really though- rendering the whole element will probably work best.

Comment: For the time, I am just rendering the whole style tag in template functions and returning that.